# Change tag default attribute's value in Seam

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I am using Seam tag `<s:decorate>`, it has a `enclose` attribute. By default it is set to `true` (You can see it in the `HtmlDecorate` class).

In my application all the tags should not be enclosed, so the attribute should be set to `false` on each tag. But to do specify it on each tag is not very beautiful solution.

I would like to change the default `enclose = true` to `false` in one place. Is it possible through injection or somehow else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I found is overriding Seam's `decorate` component with yours. While it sounds complicated, it is relatively simple to accomplish, and is better than having to write `enclose="false"` in every `<s:decorate/>`. This solution relies on the fact that component definitions located in your project's `faces-config.xml` take priority over the definitions located in the `faces-config.xml` files located inside library jars.

Create your custom component class that extends `HtmlDecorate`:

```java
public class MyDecorate extends HtmlDecorate {

    // Default value is false, as opposed to HtmlDecorate
    private boolean _myenclose = false;

    // Default constructor
    public MyDecorate() {
        super();
    }

    // Override setEnclose() and isEnclose() so that they use your variable
    public boolean isEnclose() {
       return _myenclose;
    }
    public void setEnclose(boolean enclose) {
       this._myenclose = enclose;
    }
}
```

Declare your class as the class for the decorate component, in your `faces-config.xml` (note that we specify your custom component class in the `<component-class />` tag, while using the usual Seam renderer):

```xml
<component>
    <description>"Decorate" a JSF input field when validation fails or when required="true" is set.</description>
    <component-type>org.jboss.seam.ui.Decorate</component-type>
    <component-class>com.example.myapp.MyComponent</component-class>
    <component-extension>
        <component-family>org.jboss.seam.ui.Decorate</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.jboss.seam.ui.DecorateRenderer</renderer-type>
    </component-extension>
</component>
```

Use the `<s:decorate/>` tag as usual in your pages:

```xml
<s:decorate template="...">
    ....
</s:decorate>
```

Comment: you are cool! I was trying to override it using Seam component descriptor, but it didn't work. Thank you :)